PyQt6 designer won't install. Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6: version `Qt_6.4' not found
I have attempted to install PyQt6 and its pyqt6 designer and I can't resolve the following error message when using the following command,
pyqt6-tools designer

It results in this error message,
~/projects/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qt6_applications/Qt/bin/designer: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6: version `Qt_6.4' not found (required by ~/projects/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qt6_applications/Qt/bin/designer)

To reproduce the error, I created a clean pip environment and installed the packages via,
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install PyQt6
pip install pyqt6-tools
pyqt6-tools designer

and the pyqt6-tools designer command fails with the error message shown above, I've looked at trying to solve the issue but with no success. I did see other people have had this issue (see this thread) but their solution didn't work for me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

The error message seems pretty clear. The pyqt6-tools package hasn't been updated since March 2023 and only supports Qt-6.4 / Python <= 3.9, so you'll need to downgrade everthing accordingly. Then again, if you're on Linux, why not just use the official PyQt6/Qt6 packages provided by your distro? There's no real need to install Qt Designer in the venv if you've already got it installed in your main system. The ui files and pyuic output should be pretty stable across most recent versions.

Hi @ekhumoro, thanks for the prompt response. So, one way to resolve this issue would be to downgrade python to 3.9 or below, or I could use the PyQt6/Qt6 package provided by the distro? I don't believe I have it installed (perhaps I uninstalled it without realizing?) How can I check? Thanks for the help.

Maybe learn how to use your distro's package-manager?
